# Is there a way to ask Numba not to try to compile a specific line of a function?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I've got a function which is calling a function that Numba doesn't have an implementation for, so the code fails and returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makearray.py", line 45, in <module>
    arrNp = loop(100*i)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 414, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 357, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(int64, 1d, C))
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
   - Of which 16 did not match due to:
   Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
     With argument(s): '(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(int64, 1d, C))':
    No match.

During: typing of setitem at makearray.py (39)

File "makearray.py", line 39:
def loop(zoom):
    <source elided>
            row.append(theM.real)
        arra.append(row)
        ^
```

The code is calling `loop` in a loop, and now Numba doesn't like it. Without the loop, onyl calling `loop` once, it worked. Changing `fastmath` and other Numba arguments doesn't make a difference. So, is there a way to tell Numba to let one line of code be normal Python code, so it doesn't get this error message when trying to find an optimization?

For reference, the code is this:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

nmax=50

@njit(fastmath=True)
def mandelbrot(c):
    z=0
    n=0
    while abs(z) <= 2 and n < nmax:
        z = z*z+c
        n+=1
    return n

@njit()
def loop(zoom):
    img = []
    for a in range(-1500,500+1,1):
        col = []
        for b in range(-1050,1050+1,1):
            c = complex(-np.e/7+a/(1000+zoom),b/(1000+zoom)-np.e/20)
            theM = mandelbrot(c)
            row.append(theM.real)
        img.append(row)
    imgNp = np.array(img)
    return imgNp


for i in range(50):
    imgNp = loop(100*i)
    np.save('mbsNp'+str(i).zfill(3),imgNp)
```

Comment: your `row` is not defined inside the inner loop. Did you mean `col` instead?

Comment: Assuming you meant `row` instead of `col`, this code run without any issue for me with Numba. Which version of Numba and Numpy are you using? Can you share the full error stack? And to answer your question, no, you can't tell Numba not to compile just one line. And also, it's very unlikely that the issue is cased by a loop. Numba is made to handle several layers of inner loops. The issue must be something different.